# Why is the voting for Grammy's being manipulated by the social media?

Tags: award

Many big artists have chosen not to send their songs to Grammy's anymore in protest to the company's policies in choosing the best songs and artists, including The Weeknd, Zayn, Ariana Grande, and some more.

For example, Ariana Grande and Lana Del Rey lost to Billie Eilish and Lizzo in one of the Grammy's (I think the last Grammy's Ariana Grande was in). The winners won just because their songs were hit in the social media. Speaking about the voices and the music the loser songs were so better.

Or *Watermelon Sugar* by Harry Styles won the Grammy's while his fans themselves say it's not a very valuable song among his works. It won just because it became a hit on social media like TikTok. Because people tend to like regular music more.

Is it Grammy's fault that they lost some valuable artists? Why do they value people's tendencies more than the values of songs if they are the most important body of judging and awarding musics?

Of course for the not-so-well-known genres the Grammy's really does a valuable assessment. But for big genres they do not.

Couldn't Grammy's be like Oscars to assess things based on values?

Answer (score 1):

All awards, at some level, are popularity contests. And in the arts, where there's a lot of differing, subjective opinions, there's always going to be disagreement about the winners.

In addition, the Grammys are industry awards, which tends to mean they favor what's commercially successful and well-known.

But none of this is unique. You could say the exact same thing about the Oscars. Both awards have come under fire for biases and prejudices, choosing the popular over the good, making the wrong decision, not having representative-enough voters, being a relic, being vulnerable to publicity campaigns and so forth and so on. For that matter, even the ranks of Nobel Peace Prize winners includes a couple of stinkers. It's fair to criticize the Grammys, but none of this is particularly unusual or hard to understand.

Comment: It's not unusual to choose the popular over the good. The unusual thing is that they don't tend to make it better. As I said before they missed some big singers for this reason. How many valuable artists should leave Grammys so that they reconsider? On the other hand, how many valuable filmmakers and actors/actresses have chosen to not attend Oscars?